# Is there a limit for the number of questions, answers or comments a user can make in a day?

Tags: support

I already know I can post a question only once in 40 minutes. At least, I got this message from the system when I tried to post a second question in a period of 40 minutes.

But, besides that, aren't there some particular limits for the number of questions, or answers, or comments? I would be glad to know how many I can post during one single day. I will not use that limit completely, of course; I'm just curious.

Comment: These posts may help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/ and https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/752/. The short answer is yes, there are limits and they change as you get more reputation on a site.